# Make adequate filtering or expand all in vscode extension

Tags: javascript, vscode-extensions

Greeting. I'm trying to make extension with tree view (https://github.com/DrBoria/vscode-draft-tree)

And stuck with filtering functionality. The common filter widget doesn't filter data in subfolders.

It just leaves closed folders, even if doesn't have a search criteria match:
[image]

Can anybody help with this? If it would be filter with sub folders filter - perfect. If expands all - amazing. Or at least some explanation, of how to manually trigger getChildren with new data.

Please!))

Thanks!)

I tried to make the overhead and make "expand all" button and filter after usage.
But still had no success. It just doesn't work. Here is a code sample:

```
// EXPAND ALL
this._register(vscode.commands.registerCommand('tabsTreeOpenView.expandAll', () => {
    for (const item of this.treeOpenedDataProvider.getState()) {
        if (item.type === TreeItemType.Folder && item.children.length) {
           openView.reveal(item, {expand: true});               
        }
    }
}));
```

It just did nothing. Reveal doesn't reveal elements in the tree view.
getChildren function doesn't fire with new elements.